# TypeError: Float object is not iterable in my code

Tags: python, typeerror

I have 2 separate functions in my code. One is def main and one is def calculations. Here is my code for def calculations:

```
def calculations(p1x, p1y, p2x, p2y):
    length = p2y - p1y
    width = p2x - p1x
    area = length * width
    perim = 2 * length + width
    return area
    return perim
```

Then when I try to call it in main later here:

```
area, perim = calculations(p1x, p1y, p2x, p2y)
```

I get the error

> TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable.

Comment: Float objects aren't iterable in *anyone's* code. `return perim` is never actually reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return only *one* value, `area`. The other `return` statement is never reached, because the function is done when the first `return` statement is reached.

Return both as a tuple instead:

```
return area, perim
```